# No se envía correo desde php

Tags: php

Buenas,

Estoy siguiendo las mismas pautas que la pregunta que hice hace unos días para enviar correos desde PHP, pero por más que le doy vueltas no me está funcionando para la funcionalidad con la que estoy trabajando. No es más que el usuario rellene un formulario y se me envíe al correo esa consulta.

```
$destinatario = "-@hotmail.com";   //no pongo el correo real por seguridad    
$user = isset($_SESSION['usuario']) ? $_SESSION['usuario'] : "null";    

//buscamos el correo del usuario en la base de datos

        $statement = $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE usuario = :usuario");
        $statement->execute(array(":usuario" => $user));
        $info_usuario = $statement->fetch();

        $correo = $info_usuario['correo'];

        $texto = trim($texto);

        if (!$errores) {
            $enviado = true;

            // Varios destinatarios
            $para  = $destinatario; // atención a la coma

            // título
            $título = "$asunto";

            // mensaje
            $mensaje = "
            <html>
            <head>
              <title>$asunto</title>
            </head>
            <body>
              <p>$texto</p>
            </body>
            </html>
            ";

            // Para enviar un correo HTML, debe establecerse la cabecera Content-type
            $cabeceras  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";

            // Cabeceras adicionales
            $cabeceras .= "To: $para" . "\r\n";
            $cabeceras .= "From: $correo" . "\r\n";
            /*
            $cabeceras .= 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com' . "\r\n";
            $cabeceras .= 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com' . "\r\n";
            */
            // Enviarlo
            mail($para, $título, $mensaje, $cabeceras);

        }
```

He comprobado los datos con `echo` y son correctos, así que entiendo que es que algo estoy haciendo mal a la hora de enviar el email. El correo destinatario he comprobado que es correcto.

Comment: Te muestra algún error?? Si es así lo puede indicar.

Comment: @juanitourquiza No, no me muestra ninguno. Pero en el correo no me aparece absolutamente nada, ni en spam ni en la bandeja de entrada. Es casi el mismo código que estoy usando para otra sección de la web y ahí funciona sin problemas, pero por más que miro no encuentro ningún fallo. Los valores de las variables son correctos.

Comment: Puedes poner tu función mail para ver si no hay algo raro

Comment: Lo estás probando en un servidor SMTP. Tienes un servidor de prueba?

Comment: @juanitourquiza estoy trabajando en localhost, sé lo justo del tema. Pero la misma función `mail()` la estoy usando en otra parte de la web, y funciona tanto en localhost como en la propia web.

Comment: Cual es tu sistema operativo?

Comment: @juanitourquiza Estoy usando Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Faltaría configurar el servidor SMTP . Aquí te dejo un enlace: http://theandystratton.com/2009/fix-phps-mail-function-after-latest-os-x-leopard-update

Veamos si con eso se soluciona.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si el mensaje lo estás enviado con la función mail todo depende del servidor SMTP que tengas configurado en el `php.ini`.

Si utilizas el servidor SMTP local de tu equipo habría que ver si tienes configurado un forwarder (otro servidor SMTP al que rediriges todo el correo) y si te estás autenticando con usuario y clave en dicho servidor.

Desde hace ya bastante tiempo la mayoría de servidores de correo no suelen aceptar mensajes de correo que vengan de equipos que no sean un servidor de correo, y se suelen denegar la recepción de mensajes de equipos que no tengan contratada una IP fija.

Personalmente te recomendaria que modificases tu código y utilizases una librería como puede ser [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) la cual te permite meter en tu código el servidor de correo, usuario y clave para autenticarte en él.

Comment: Pero lo que no entiendo es, ¿por qué sí que me está funcionando en otra sección de la web en local y en la propia web? Es lo que no entiendo, de hecho en la sección donde estoy trabajando antes funcionaba perfectamente, simplemente que el código era muy escaso y el correo aunque se enviaba con toda la información, no estaba bien ordenado.

Comment: Utilizabas en ambos sitios la función mail() ?

Comment: @netVicius Sí así es.

Comment: Es decir, mismo servidor, misma configuración. En un script php funciona, y en otro no. ¿correcto? Alguna diferencia en ambos códigos reseñable? Porque te da error directamente al enviar, o es que los emails no llegan ? Si usas hotmail/gmail o similar has mirado si está en la carpeta del spam?

Comment: he probado a subirlo a la web y los mails se envían, imagino que será algún problema con Xampp que tendría que configurar.

Comment: Como te comenté en la respuesta, no es lo mismo tu equipo que tiene IP dinámica, que el servidor que seguramente estará alojado en una máquina con IP fija. Modifica el código utilizando por ejemplo PHPMailer y problema solucionado seguro.